# Access a file in Android and automatically open it when a button is clicked

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I have a Kivy app with a file that generates and opens a file in the default web browser when a button is clicked. Although, I can't seem to get it to work when it is deployed on the Android phone. Attached below is both my Python code and also the buildozer.spec file.

Buildozer.spec File:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = BFCalc4

# (str) Package name
package.name = bfcalc4

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,gif,ico,html

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,datetime

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/BFloading.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/icon.ico

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = Â© Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =

# Control passing the --use-setup-py vs --ignore-setup-py to p4a
# "in the future" --use-setup-py is going to be the default behaviour in p4a, right now it is not
# Setting this to false will pass --ignore-setup-py, true will pass --use-setup-py
# NOTE: this is general setuptools integration, having pyproject.toml is enough, no need to generate
# setup.py if you're using Poetry, but you need to add "toml" to source.include_exts.
#p4a.setup_py = false


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.10.0

# (bool) Whether or not to sign the code
ios.codesign.allowed = false

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Python Code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
import webbrowser
from datetime import datetime

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

answers = []

class CalcScreen(Screen):
    def list_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "list_screen"
    def cround_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "round_calc_screen"
    def calculate(self):
        LengthVal = float(self.ids.length.text)
        WidthVal = float(self.ids.width.text)
        ThicknessVal = float(self.ids.thickness.text)

        FinalCalc = LengthVal * WidthVal * ThicknessVal / 144
        FinalCalc = round(FinalCalc,1)
        answers.append(FinalCalc)

        self.ids.board_feet.text = str(FinalCalc)

class ListScreen(Screen):
    def calc_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "calc_screen"
    def UpdateInfo(self):
        tot = 0
        for num in answers:
            tot += num

        self.ids.total_board_feet.text = str(round(tot,1))
        self.ids.total_boards.text = str(len(answers))
        self.ids.list.text = str(', '.join(map(str, answers)))
    def ClearListAnswers(self):
        answers.clear()
    def printerview(self):
        current_datetime = datetime.now()
        format_date = current_datetime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

        file_name = "printerfriendly.html"
        html = f"<h1>BFCalc Printer Friendly View</h1>\n<h3>{format_date}</h3><h5>List: {self.ids.list.text}</h5>\n<h5>Total Board Feet: {self.ids.total_board_feet.text}</h5>\n<h5>Total Boards: {self.ids.total_boards.text}</h5>"

        with open(file_name, "w+") as f:
            f.write(html)

        webbrowser.open(file_name)

class RoundCalcScreen(Screen):
    def calc_view(self):
        self.manager.current = "calc_screen"
    def rc_calculate(self):
        RC_DiameterVal = float(self.ids.rc_diameter.text)
        RC_RadiusVal = RC_DiameterVal / 2
        RC_ThicknessVal = float(self.ids.rc_thickness.text)

        RC_FinalCalc = (3.14 * (RC_RadiusVal * RC_RadiusVal) * RC_ThicknessVal) / 144
        RC_FinalCalc = round(RC_FinalCalc,1)
        answers.append(RC_FinalCalc)

        self.ids.rc_board_feet.text = str(RC_FinalCalc)

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.icon = 'icon.ico'
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to request the permissions in your code, like this:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

See [this](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#runtime-permissions)

Comment: Will this work with my current code or do I have to change anything in my code for it to work. Like the directory that the file is stored in.

Comment: Try it. See if that is enough.

Comment: Alright, I tried it but it didn't work. The app closed when I clicked the button. I got an error that is below.
`jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=printerfriendly.html }`

Comment: So it looks like the file write is working. The error is when you try to open the file with `webbrowser`. Try changing the argument of `webbrowser.open()` to a `url` (`file://`) form instead of a file name. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) says that a file name is neither supported nor portable.

Comment: So what would I change that to?

Comment: Try `webbrowser.open(pathlib.Path(os.path.abspath(file_name)).as_uri())`.

Comment: Alright, I have tried that but it gave me another error.
`jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: file:///data/data/org.test.bfcalc4/files/app/printerfriendly.html exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()`

Comment: So that means that the file is written in a folder that is private to the app, and the web browser cannot read it. You need to write the file in a public area. Try using [primary_external_storage_path()](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis/#storage-paths) to get a folder that is accessible by the web browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221521/discussion-between-luciorandy-and-john-anderson).

Answer (score 0):

```
    def printerview(self):
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    format_date = current_datetime.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

    file_name = "printerfriendly.html"
    html = f"<h1>BFCalc Printer Friendly View</h1>\n<h3>{format_date}</h3><h5>List: {self.ids.list.text}</h5>\n<h5>Total Board Feet: {self.ids.total_board_feet.text}</h5>\n<h5>Total Boards: {self.ids.total_boards.text}</h5>"

    with open(file_name, "w+") as f:
        f.write(html)
        f.close()

    webbrowser.open(file_name)
```

You have to close the file to view the written content.